# Given $A$, $b$, and $V=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^3:Ax=b\}$, find $\textit{all}$ values of $a,b,c$ for which the following statements are true

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $A=\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1&a&2\\1&1&b \end{array}\right)$ and $b=\left(\begin{array}{c} c\\-c \end{array}\right)$.

(a) $V$ is empty.

(b) $V$ is a plane.

(c) $V$ is a subspace.

Here's what I have so far:

(a) Here, we are looking for all $a,b,c$ such that
$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1&a&2\\1&1&b \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c} c\\-c \end{array}\right)$$
has no solutions. We'll first re-write this as a system of equations: $x_1+ax_2+2x_3=c$ and $x_1+x_2+bx_3=-c$. Then, subtracting the second equation from the first, we have $(a-1)x_2+(2-b)x_3=2c$. Thus, $V$ is empty whenever $a=1, b=2, c\neq0$.

(b) I'm a bit lost on this. For $V$ to be a plane, we require that it is spanned by 2 linearly independent vectors. I'm not sure what to do with this info, however.

(c) For $V$ to be a subspace, we require that it is non-empty, closed under vector addition, and closed under scalar multiplication. I believe there are no values of $a,b,c$ that satisfy closure under vector addition. For example, let $x,y\in V$. Then for $x+y$ to be in $V$, we need that $$\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 1&a&2\\1&1&b \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}x_1+y_1\\x_2+y_2\\x_3+y_3\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c} c\\-c \end{array}\right)$$ Then, solving this system of equations, we get $2(x_1+y_1)+(a+1)(x_2+y_2)+(2+b)(x_3+y_3)=0$. Since there are no values of $a$ and $b$ that ensure this is true for arbitrary $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^3$, $V$ is never a subspace.

Comment: For (b): rank of the matrix must [necessarily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) be $3-2=1$. For (c): $x=0$ must belong to $V$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a)  Your solution is correct.

(b)  $$(a-1)x_2+(2-b)x_3=2c$$ is an equation of plain if $a\ne 1$ or $b\ne 2$

(c)  Only if $c=0$ you  have a homogeneous system,closure, and subspace.

Comment: For (b), should it be $a\neq1 \textit{or}$ $b\neq2$?

Comment: You are correct. I have fixed it. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Atsina For $a\ne 1$ or $b\ne 2$ you will get *one* free variable, and as a result, an equation of *line*. For example, $a=1$, $b=0$, $c=1$: $x_1+x_2=-1$, $x_3=1$.